# Spam Firewall for Exchange 2013 Environment

Tags: spam, exchange-2013, barracuda

We are currently using Exchange 2013 and we are interested in the Barracuda Spam Firewall. We are trying to figure out a way around our current email flow setup.
We currently have multiple users with auto-forwards/transport rules that send a copy of their messages to other users. So any email UserA receives, a copy goes to UserB. We are trying to eliminate the Barracuda spam quarantine message report from being forward. Perhaps a condition in the transport rule to exclude Barracuda quarantine messages?? Can the Barracuda send the quarantine reports to 1 user mailbox which then can be forwarded to each user?

Answer (score 2):

I've sold/deployed lots of Barracuda Spam Filters over the year. I don't use the quarantine feature in *any* of my deployments. Without even addressing the unique mail flow issues you have (*use distribution groups?*), it's not necessary. Is there a reason your users would request the quarantine functionality?

Comment: What would some of the options be for notifying users that they have questionable emails? We were hoping to put the users in-control over their own white-list/black-list using the quarantine message report sent multiple times a day.

Comment: The whole point of Barracuda's RBL and Spam Detection techniques is to eliminate the need for that.

Comment: @user268322 I would add that if your user fear to miss important email, just make sure NDR are sent. Better than having a email laying in a quarantine that they can miss.